# How to view users logged in since last 5 minutes in linux command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, last

I am fairly new to linux and trying to learn the terminal commands.

I want to see the list of users who logged in since last 5 minutes.

I searched the internet but almost every place solution uses a shell-script. But I want to see this using just a command.

I tried

```
last -t -5min
```

Is it right? I cannot know for sure since I am the only user on my system.

Comment: @Fox That helped. Thank you. But **last -s -5min** will give right answer to my command right?

Comment: I created another user and checked it. It works